# How to allocate DMA descriptor in u-boot

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, u-boot

In Linux kernel , we can allocate DMA descriptor(structure containing DMA controller property) using dma_alloc_coherent but I don't see such an api in u-boot source .

How can we allocate DMA descriptor in u-boot?

From given source https://github.com/siemens/u-boot/blob/master/drivers/dma/apbh_dma.c#L339

```
/*
* Allocate DMA descriptor
*/
struct mxs_dma_desc *mxs_dma_desc_alloc(void)
{
struct mxs_dma_desc *pdesc;
uint32_t size;

size = roundup(sizeof(struct mxs_dma_desc), MXS_DMA_ALIGNMENT);
pdesc = memalign(MXS_DMA_ALIGNMENT, size);

if (pdesc == NULL)
    return NULL;

memset(pdesc, 0, sizeof(*pdesc));
pdesc->address = (dma_addr_t)pdesc;

return pdesc;
};
```

I can see that descriptor is allocated using memalign but how it would make sure that allocation is from consistent memory ?

Comment: U-Boot typically does not enable the processor caches, so all memory is therefore consistent.

Comment: Thanks for reply , I am just looking at this file https://github.com/longsleep/u-boot-pine64/blob/pine64-hacks/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/sun50iw1p1/board.c and wanted to initialize  one of subsystem which uses DMA desc but not sure where to put this call so that it should not be called before cache_disable?

Comment: Also just few days back This patch is posted https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/598917/ which says cache Enable caches for the RPi2 in u-boot .How things would be different now as far as memory consistent goes ?

Comment: Study the U-Boot README file for CONFIG_SYS_NONCACHED_MEMORY regarding a region of memory that is not cached.  The SoCs I use do not have data-cache enabled in U-Boot, so that's all I know.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. It would read it   :)